# PHPMyAdmin fails with PHP 5.5.3

Tags: phpmyadmin, loading

PHPMyAdmin 4.0.5 works with PHP 5.4.13; with 5.5.3, it fails:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function PMA_DBI_num_rows() in
C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\navigation\Nodes\Node.class.php on line 408

PHPMyAdmin 4.0.6 with PHP 5.5.3 gives:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function PMA_DBI_num_rows() in
C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\navigation\Nodes\Node.class.php on line 397

Windows service: Apache/2.4.4(Win32)PHP/5.5.3

Why?

Answer (score 1):

In phpMyAdmin 4.0.7, a fix has been done to show a proper error message for this issue. See https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3997/ for a possible cause of your problem (missing PHP extensions for MySQL).